# Sound not working on MacBook Air mute box is checked and greyed out

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

My audio on my MacBook Air is not working. When I go into System Preferences and go to Sound, the mute box is checked and greyed out. My Mac can't play anything including iTunes and YouTube, even system sounds such as the sound when you send an email.

I have reset the NVRAM and repaired the disk using Disk Utility. I also went into Terminal and ran `sudo killall coreaudiod` but that didn't work either.

When I turn on the laptop it doesn't make a startup chime like it normally would. My headphone jack does not have a red light in it and it shows I have no audio output or input.

Comment: hello i dont understand what you just said im sorry but could you please reword that? @jm666

Answer (score 1):

Devon, I did some investigating on the apple support site and found this. 

1) Delete both files in YourHardDrive->Library->Preferences->Audio -> (both .plist files in this folder)
com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist 
com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist 

2) Make sure to empty your trash. 

3) Reboot 

Let us know if this works! 

Apple Support Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23538716#23538716

Comment: hey thanks for responding but i looked in my hard drive- preferences- audio- and only found one file.  the only file there was the device setting .plist file so i put it in the trash and emptied it.  then i did the restart and nothing changed. @cstaley

Comment: I have a Macbook Air "Early 2014", and just the boot sound was working, but then sound after login wasn't working. I think your suggestion here *might* have been what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had precisely this problem with a MacBook Air. The Air was propped on its side and dropped onto the floor. Afterwards the sounds controls were greyed out.

The problem is that the cable between the sound card and the motherboard had loosened. I opened up the laptop, removed the cable and re-attached it. The problem went away.